# can ffmpeg record acestreaming on centos?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, record

I have a acestream link, like : acestream://f4d77a80fa28f0a34ded0132dc1952ec328f6998 . Can I record this video with ffmpeg on Centos ?
acestream have client in centos here : http://wiki.acestream.org/wiki/index.php/Streaming/en  but I still don't know how to use it. How to put acestream:// link to it and play video.
Anyone did this before ?

I can do this with sopcast, https://github.com/NapoleonWils0n/cerberus/blob/master/sopcast/sopcast-install.sh . Now I want to try with acestream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not make it work with ffmpeg, but mpv seems to work fine:

```
$ acestream-launcher -p "mpv --stream-record=out.ts" ACESTREAM_URL
```